# Changing the reference of an array with a function not working

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

The following works...

```
$a = ['a','b','c'=>[1,2,3]];
$b = &$a;
$b = &$b['c'];
```

So... I want to change the reference of an array with this function:

```
function change_array_pointer ( &$array, $path ) {    
    foreach ($path as $subpath) {
        $array = &$array[$subpath];
    }    
}
```

Looks simple, but doesn't work.

For example, this code is not working and I don't know why:

```
$a = ['a','b','c'=>[1,2,3]];
$b = &$a;
change_array_pointer($b,['c']);
```

In my opinion $b should be [1,2,3], but it's not.

Please explain to me what's happening :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = &$array[$subpath];
```

References in php are not like C pointers. Change that with

```
$array = $array[$subpath];
```

[What References Are](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php)